# Scaling images in an image view with a fixed width

Tags: android, android-layout

I have several images I lazyload into a ListActivity. Now the thing is that the images have different aspect ratios.

I would like all images to display with the same width set in xml (to fit into my layout), while taking as much space hightwise as they need.
Is there a way to do that in xml?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you want `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`

From the sdk docs at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit.html#CENTER:

Compute a scale that will maintain the original src aspect ratio, but will also ensure that src fits entirely inside dst. At least one axis (X or Y) will fit exactly. The result is centered inside dst.

So, I think if you set a width on the imageview but set the height to wrap_content you should get what you want with the scaleType fitCenter.

Comment: Not working for me. That way the images do keep their aspect ratio, but the height (where i set wrap_content) stays as small as the original bitmap heigth. So the picture isnt rescaled...

Comment: Hmmm, then I guess you'd have to try setting the imageviews to wrap_content on both dimensions, then alter your lazy loading to do the scaling for you. Since you know the width you want, just use the bitmap apis to scale the height according to the ratio between your target width and the width of the source image.

Comment: Yes, thats sounds like to be the only way. It's a shame it can't be done from xml.

Comment: hey i am also having same problem did you find a solution for it ??

Comment: Same problem here... I used the bitmap api to resize but thatś a shame we cannot do dot in a more easy way

Comment: I had written a custom method to resize `Bitmap`s according to the desired aspect ratio + width. But it is prone to `OutOfMemoryException` especially on custom roms. Are there better libraries to achieve the same?